# How do I find if an id exists in more than one instance of another column?

Tags: mysql

How can I query table 1 to give me records where id2 exists more than once in id1?

```
table 1
id1, id2
1,100
1,99
1,98
2,100
2,101
2,102
```

So the desired result would be

```
1,100
2,100
```

Comment: You may find 'group by id1' and  'having count(id2) >= 2' useful? The 'having' clause is the same as a 'where' clause but applies to 'groups' rather than individual rows.

Comment: @ryanvincent If you group by `ID1` but try to return both `id1` and `id2` you will get a random `id2` value back for each distinct `id1` (in MySQL 5.6 or older). In MySQL 5.7 or newer you will just get an error. If you omit `id2` from the output and apply that `HAVING` clause you will end up with two records for `id1` in the return: `1` and `2` which is sort of useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is a subquery to get `id2` values that show up more than once in your table. Then return records from the table that contain those `id2` values. There's a few ways to do this.

[Here is one using the `IN` clause and just hitting a list returned by a subquery:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f966e62/3)

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM table1 
WHERE id2 IN (SELECT id2 FROM table1 GROUP BY id2 HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

[And another using a correlated subquery](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f966e62/4) which may prove useful if your data is larger

```
SELECT id1, id2 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id2 FROM table1 WHERE t1.id2 = id2 GROUP BY id2 HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following query to determine if an id exists in more than one instance of another column:

```
select id1, id2
from table
group by id2
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I don't believe this will return what OP is after. It will return `100` for id2 and, randomly, either `1` or `2` for `id1`. In Mysql 5.7 or newer it will throw an error unless they have flipped their ALWAYS_FULL_GROUP_BY setting off. [sqlfiddle of mysql5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f966e62/1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use une a join with id2 like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id1
    ,t1.id2
FROM
    table1 as t1
inner join table1 as t2 on t2.id2 = t1.id2
```

Comment: Not sure where you were going with this one, but this returns some oddball cross join, not the two records OP is after.